# Service Intent Must Be Explict

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am trying to launch a service with a predefined action but i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.radioafrica.music.action.TOGGLE_PLAYBACK }
        at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1745)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1774)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1758)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:515)
        at com.radioafrica.music.activity.MusicPlayer.onClick(MusicPlayer.java:70)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4763)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19821)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

The code i use to try and launch the intent is as follows:

```
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PLAY);
 startService(serviceIntent);
```

This doesnt work as well;

```
startService(new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PLAY);
```

I have already included the appropriate intent filters in the manifest too.

Comment: is this service a service in your project or from another app?

Comment: @tyczj it's in my project

Comment: so why are you starting your service like that? You should be starting your service with something like `new Intent(context,MyService.class)`

Comment: you have to define it explicitly for android version > kitkat check this link : http://blog.android-develop.com/2014/10/android-l-api-21-javalangillegalargumen.html

Comment: Yeah. Made the change and all is fine now. Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android 5.0+, you can no longer bind to a service, using `bindService()`, via an implicit `Intent`. An implicit `Intent` is one where you use things like an action string, rather than identifying the specific Java class in the specific app that you wish to bind to.

You have a few options, including:

1. `startService()` is unaffected, so you could look to change your protocol for interacting with the service to the command pattern, rather that the binding pattern, and you can stick with your existing `Intent`.
2. If this is your own service, get rid of the `<intent-filter>`, and use the `Intent` constructor that takes the Java class as the second parameter (e.g., `new Intent(this, MusicThingyService.class)`). The only reason for having an `<intent-filter>` on a service is if you want third parties to work with that service.
3. If you know the application ID of the app that is hosting the service that you want, calling `setPackage()` on the `Intent` that you are using will make it "explicit enough" to satisfy `bindService()`.
4. You can use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentServices()` to find the service implementation(s). This will allow you to fail gracefully if there are no matching services (e.g., your partner app is not installed), more than one matching service (e.g., somebody else is trying to intercept communications), or malware masquerading as the matching service (via checking the signature of the other app). I demonstrate this approach in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding/SigCheck).