# How do you use bindService() in Android to bind to a Service in another apk?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, bind

How do I make an Intent in my client that refers to the Service class in my(a) **service that is packaged in another apk**?  In an a service is defined:

`public class SSMservice extends Service {`

```
<service android:name=".SSMservice"
   android:exported="true" android:label="SSMsvc" />
```

In another apk, I have a client that wants to bind to that service:

```
public static ServiceConnection ssmConn;
public static Messenger ssmMsngr;
  ...
  if (ssmConn == null) {
      ssmConn = new ServiceConnection() {
          @Override
          public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
              ssmMsngr = null;
          }

          @Override
          public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
              // We are connected to the service
              ssmMsngr = new Messenger(service);
          }
      };

      // We bind to the service
      bindService(new Intent(app, SSMservice.class), ssmConn,   <--SSMservice class is unknown
        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

The **bindService()** method needs and Intent (which I made a 'component' Intent, ie, not an implicit Intent).  To identify the class that contains the service in the other apk, I need a reference to the class that is in the service apk (and not known to client apk)

Solution, per comments from MikeM and CommonWare:

```
    Intent ssmIntent = new Intent().setClassName("ribo.ssm",
      "ribo.ssm.SSMservice");
    app.bindService(ssmIntent, ssmConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Rather than trying to use Intent with a specific class, or Intent.setClass(...)
the Itent.setClassName(String pkgName, String className) method allows effectively identifying the requested class without needing to have access to the class directly.

I may try another technique by having an  with an  in the  definition in the service's AndroidManifest.xml and searching with an intent created with Intent.addAction(String).  That way the client doesn't need to know something as intimate as the name of the package or a class in that package.

Per Mike M, this sort of code:

```
PackageManager pm = app.getPackageManager();
Intent it = new 
Intent().setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");//.setPackage("ribo.ssm");
List<ResolveInfo> acts = pm.queryIntentActivities(it, 0);
for (ResolveInfo ri : acts) {
  prt("actRI "+ri);
}

it = new Intent().setClassName("ribo.ssm", "ribo.ssm.SSMservice");
List<ResolveInfo> svcs = pm.queryIntentServices(it, 0);
for (ResolveInfo ri : svcs) {
  prt("RI "+ri);
}
```

helped me to see what activites and services Android would find when it tried to do a startActivity or bindService.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32332503/115145 -- see options 3 and 4. See also [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/29/dealing-deprecations-bindservice.html) and [this pair of samples](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Binding/Remote).

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm thinking that [package visibility in 11](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/package-visibility) is gonna apply to binding external `Service`s, too, yeah? I haven't tested it yet, but they do mention "Explicit interactions with other apps, such as `startService()`, ...", so I would assume binding is restricted, as well. (The `queryIntentServices()` suggestion in #4 would certainly be affected, anyway, I would think.)

Comment: @MikeM.: Agreed, the Android 11 package visibility affects this. The app doing the binding will need a `<queries>` element in the manifest. [This sample client](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/v0.2/EmbedClient) has one, for binding to [this sample service](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/v0.2/EmbedServer).